# Capistrano multi stage deployment acts weird with bundler (path problems)

Tags: capistrano, bundler

I have this really weird problem with capistrano/bundler and I am so stuck...
I have two stages: production and staging
when I execute `cap production bundle:install` it works well and runs this:

```
executing "cd /var/www/whatever/releases/20110506112617 && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/whatever/releases/20110506112617/Gemfile --path /var/www/whatever/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
```

everything fine, however when I run `cap staging bundle:install` I get this:

```
failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/staging.whatever/releases/shared && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/staging.whatever/releases/shared/Gemfile --path /var/www/staging.whatever/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on whatever.org
```

It should not be

```
sh -c 'cd /var/www/staging.whatever/releases/shared && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/staging.whatever/releases/shared/Gemfile
```

but instead

```
sh -c 'cd /var/www/staging.whatever/releases/20110506112617 && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/staging.whatever/releases/20110506112617/Gemfile
```

something is wrong with the current_path and I don't know why... it always points to releases/shared which is totally wrong...

I run capistrano 2.6.0, any help is highly appreciated

-- Flo

Comment: Is the `:deploy_to` path altered in the stage.rb deploy file?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem when bundler executes at the end of my `cap production deploy`, where it has the same kind of "failed" line you're seeing.

Comment: Any luck on this? I also just started having similar problems. My recipe for dev-stage works, but production is failing with bundler not accessing the Gemfile.lock, I get "The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have checked your Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying." It's checked in

Answer (score 3):

Simply delete the "shared" release

```
rm -rf /var/www/staging.whatever/releases/shared
```

Comment: Ya this worked for me. I have no idea how `/var/www/XXX/releases/shared` was created in the first place. Any ideas?

Comment: You might have specified `/var/www/XXX/releases/shared` for your log or pid file once.  Since Capistrano order folders by name DESC and take the first, `shared` always comes first.

There might be a lot of other reasons though ;)